# Help to fix strange sqlite3 error - dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.1, osx-leopard

I am suddenly getting an sqlite3 error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I have no idea why I am suddenly getting this error.  Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.2 Mac OSX 10.5.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so this is a messed up sqlite3 install and it seems that lots of people run into this problem but solutions are a little hard to come by.  After a lot of googling I did the following:

Step1:  went to http://www.sqlite.org/download.html and downloaded sqlite-autoconf-3070800.tar.gz under source code

Step2:  expand file and cd into the resultant directory

Step3:  sudo CFLAGS='-arch i686 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-arch i686 -arch x86_64' ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking

Step4:  sudo make install

Step5:  added /usr/local/lib to the path

I was doing an awful lot of tinkering during this time.  It's possible that I have done something else along the way and not realized and not included it here.  But these steps seemed to fix the problem for me.

My environment:   Mac OSX 10.5.8 MacBookPro4, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.5 GHz

Answer (score 4):

Thank you so much, in my case I had to rearrange the parameters and I didn't use sudo to configure nor to make:

make clean

./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr CFLAGS='-arch i686 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-arch i686 -arch x86_64'

make

sudo make install

I didn't have to modify the path, I specified in the --prefix="my path"

Environment Mac OS X v.10.5.8 2GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

Comment: Yeah - it's a bugger when this is messed up isn't it :-) ...it took me so bloody long to google around to find the answer I just had to share it.  Glad you found it useful.  If it helps you out don't forget to vote it up :-) ...points are always nice!

Answer (score 2):

Exactly same problem but the solutions here didn't work for me.
Instead reinstalling sqlite3 gem fixed the problem for me.

Environment: Mac OS X v. 10.6.8, iMac

Comment: Yeah it's a bugger of a problem.  I think it's so finicky we all find slightly different solutions work - but it's good to have them all here so folks can try each suggestion.