# Rubymine install or problems with sqlite3 install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubymine

Can anyone help me here - I am pretty sure there's something up with my sqlite3 install and I can't find clear step by step instructions on fixing it?  It has manifested itself this time as a Rubymine startup error...

```
Process:         rubymine [1351]
Path:            /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine
Identifier:      com.jetbrains.rubymine
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [739]

Interval Since Last Report:          390 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  0 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1

Date/Time:       2011-09-21 15:01:17.659 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L30)
Report Version:  6
Anonymous UUID:  [i guess i should edit this to make it anonymous]

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

That last bit - the DYLD ERROR MESSAGE bit - I have seen that before recently so I don't think that's a result of any problem with rubymine.  Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this question has the same answer as the question I posed here:

[Help to fix strange sqlite3 error - dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368392/help-to-fix-strange-sqlite3-error-dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-lib-libsqlite)

They're both ultimately down to somehow having got a messed up install of sqlite3 - however, most of the straightforward ways of installing new versions of sqlite3 didn't fix the problem again. Took an awful lot of googling to figure out the answer to this.

So... I'll put the answer in just one place, on the above referenced question.